# HttpWebRequest - Request Termination

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, connection-timeout

sorry my bad English. I using HttpWebRequest every 10 seconds. But sometime, response is wait very long time. And after the 10 seconds, next process coming. Thus, requests are stacked up. Due to the measures taken by the company in the headquarters, I am banned because the previous connection has not closed. I set the properties of the request like Timeout, ContinueTimeout, ReadWriteTimeout, but the result did not change. Actually, it falls into Exception. But when I watch "Charles Proxy", the request is still waiting for a response. But I have to stop it in some way. I share my codes and Charles's picture. Thank you for your answers already. Best regards.

[image: Still Wait Response.]

```
        string jsondata = "";
        const string url = "https://website.com";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        NameValueCollection header_items = GetHeaders();
        req.Headers.Add(header_items);
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.Host = "website.com";
        req.Accept = "application/json, text/plain, */*";
        req.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";
        req.KeepAlive = false;
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)";
        req.Referer = "https://website.com";
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        req.ContinueTimeout = 5000;
        req.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;
        req.Timeout = 5000;
        req.ContentLength = 0;
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11;
        ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 500;
        ServicePointManager.DnsRefreshTimeout = 0;
        ServicePointManager.MaxServicePointIdleTime = 5000;
        ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(delegate { return true; });
        try
        {
            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    jsondata = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    reader.Close();
                }
                response.Close();
            }
            if (jsondata.Length > 200)
            {
                //Do Something
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            req.Abort();
            //Do Something
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            req.Abort();
            //Do Something
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting up the proxy settings for your request. Many times looking up for the proxy takes too log for `HttpWebRequest`:

```
req.Proxy = GetSystemWebProxy();
```

Take a look at this also: https://en.code-bude.net/2013/01/21/3-things-you-should-know-to-speed-up-httpwebrequest/

Comment: I have studied and applied the subject you have given, but nothing has changed.